# ERROR : argument of AND must be type boolean, not type text

Tags: mysql, sql

I got confused with my query bellow ,what's wrong with it, please?

```
SELECT * FROM my_table 
WHERE 
    col_A <> 'Hello'
    AND col_B <> 'Holla'
    AND col_B <> 'Bonjour'

    AND (CASE WHEN col_c = 6 AND Language_col = 'Fr'THEN 'Français'
       WHEN col_c  = 9  AND Language_col = 'Fr'THEN 'Français'        
       WHEN col_c  = 12 AND Language_col = 'Eng' THEN 'English'
       WHEN col_c  = 4 AND Language_col = 'US' THEN 'Engish'
       ELSE Language END)

order by Date_col
```

I get this type of error :

> ERROR: argument of AND must be type boolean, not type text

Comment: Skip the `case` expression, use `AND`/`OR` instead!

Comment: may you please tell me how, i'm kinda new on this heheh ^^ thank you

Comment: What do you expect to happen if  col_c = 6 AND Language_col = 'Fr'?

Comment: Using hardcoded values like 6, 8, 12 etc in a query is usually a bad idea. How can we know what those values mean?

Comment: if col_c = 6 AND Language_col = 'Fr' i  put 'Français' in a new column i've add ...AS new_col jut right after the last END but had error :  syntax error at or near "as"

Comment: See [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query) for providing example data and expected result so we can stop geussing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a new column, then the `case` expression needs to go into the `select`, not the `where`:

```
SELECT t.*,        
       (CASE WHEN col_c = 6 AND Language_col = 'Fr' THEN 'Français'
             WHEN col_c = 9 AND Language_col = 'Fr' THEN 'Français'        
             WHEN col_c = 12 AND Language_col = 'Eng' THEN 'English'
             WHEN col_c = 4 AND Language_col = 'US' THEN 'English'
             ELSE Language
        END)
FROM my_table t
WHERE col_A <> 'Hello' AND
      col_B NOT IN ( 'Holla', 'Bonjour' )
ORDER BY Date_col ;
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to add some filter value for case when -

```
SELECT * FROM my_table 
WHERE 
    col_A <> 'Hello'
    AND col_B not in ('Holla', 'Bonjour')
    AND (CASE WHEN col_c = 6 AND Language_col = 'Fr'THEN 'Français'
       WHEN col_c  = 9  AND Language_col = 'Fr'THEN 'Français'        
       WHEN col_c  = 12 AND Language_col = 'Eng' THEN 'English'
       WHEN col_c  = 4 AND Language_col = 'US' THEN 'Engish'
       ELSE Language END in ('Français','English'))
order by Date_col
```

Comment: Thank you , but it doesn't work i get an umpty data base :/

Answer (score 0):

In PostgreSQL I needed to filter results with true and false values and the workable query I found is like this:

```
... where "Is_Paid"::boolean = true
```